# Switch Renderings In Placeholder

Tags: experience-editor

Is it possible to build a command button that swaps all renderings in one placeholder with another? I'd expect this button to show up when the placeholder itself is selected but I'm not sure how I would go about writing a command for this that content editors could use in Experience Editor. I would think that this command would have to parse the xml of the various rendering fields on an item (and its standard values renderings?). That sounds dangerous to try to do manually though.